# Why Random variable is only returning 1 character

Tags: javascript, html

Hey guys im trying to generate a random password using upper and lowercase keys + numbers. the code seems to work but instead of returning 20 characters its instead returning only 1. The return seems random.
The element should be replaced why the random password every time the button is clicked.

HTML

```
<button id = "button5" onclick = "password()">Generate password </button> 
<p4 id = "p4" > Your password will apear here </p4>
```

This is the Javascript

```
function password (length ) {
var ranpassword = "";
var chara = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"


var charalength = chara.length // there is an outside variable defining charalength = ""; I could not include that here 
for (var i = 0; <length ; i++) {
ranpassword +=  chara.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() *
chara.length));
return ranpassword;

}
document.getElementById("p4").innerHTML = "hello there " + ranpassword;
console.log(password(20));

}
```

whenver the button is clicked, one random letter is returned in console.log and i cant seem to understand why ? Can anyone tell me why?
Any help would be great . Thanks :)

Comment: Honestly, 1 character is impressive considering your for loop should have caused an error `for (var i = 0; <length ; i++) `. You are missing `i` in the comparison.

Comment: What do you mean ? where do i include the comparison "i" at ?

Comment: because you have the `return` **in** the loop's body ... Do a proper indention and you will see the problem ...

Comment: i took out the return and now it works

Comment: And you have a synatx error in the loop's declaration (but that's maybe only a typo) `for (var i = 0; ***i is missing here*** < length; i++)`

Comment: oh actually i did include the i, i just forgot to include it in the code. the problem was the return statement, I believe it stopped the code from running multiple times and stopped it after reaching one, that is why it only returned one character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did some mistake. Try this code,

```js
function password (length) {
    let ranpassword = "",
        chara = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
        charalength = chara.length;

    for (var i = 0; i<length ; i++) {
        ranpassword +=  chara.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() *
        chara.length));
    }

    document.getElementById("p4").innerHTML = "hello there " + ranpassword;
}
```

```html
<button id = "button5" onclick="password(20)">Generate password </button> 
<p4 id = "p4" > Your password will apear here </p4>
```

Comment: thank you, i actually figured it out 2 seconds before you posted. Gives me an error that the call stack size was exceeded but it still works anyways. Thank you !

Comment: @aguywithquestions Okay Great!

Answer (score 0):

Aside from your `password` function implementation partly wrong, you are not passing a `length` to `password()` function in your `onclick` handler.
You need to pass the `length` as well like `password(20)`:

```html
<button id = "button5" onclick = "password(20)">Generate password </button>
```

Comment: ohhh okay, i did not know that, thank you

Answer (score 0):

as @Locke said, your for loop syntax is incorrect, as You are missing `i` in the comparison. Other than that, you code is flooded with typos. You didn't close the for loop, and you didn't need to return `ranpassword`. Now your code works, notice that the number I put as a parameter in the onclick in the HTML is the length your password will be. Also, instead of using `.chatAt`, I generate a random number and add it to `ranpassword`. For example: The for loop gets chara[4], so randpassword has chara's 5th letter.

```js
function password(length) {
  var ranpassword = "";
  var chara = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"


  var charalength = chara.length // there is an outside variable defining charalength = ""; I could not include that here 
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    ranpassword += chara[(Math.floor(Math.random() *
      chara.length))];
  }
  document.getElementById("p4").innerHTML = "hello there " + ranpassword;
}
```

```html
<button id = "button5" onclick = "password(4)">Generate password </button> 
<p4 id = "p4" > Your password will apear here </p4>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem

```
function password(length) {
  var ranpassword = "";
  var chara = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  var charalength = chara.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    ranpassword += chara.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * chara.length));
  }
  return ranpassword;
}

console.log(password(5));
```

you were returning the password form the loop so it was returning a single character